# Unix - copy contents of one directory to another

Tags: file, unix, copy, directory

```
Folder1/
    -fileA.txt
    -fileB.txt
    -fileC.txt

> mkdir Folder2/

> [copy command]
```

And now `Folder2/` looks like:

```
Folder2/
    -fileA.txt
    -fileB.txt
    -fileC.txt
```

How to make this happen? I have tried `cp -r Folder1/ Folder2/` but I ended up with:

```
Folder2/
    Folder1/
        -fileA.txt
        -fileB.txt
        -fileC.txt
```

Which is close but not exactly what I wanted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Try this:

```
cp Folder1/* Folder2/
```

Comment: but this won't copy hidden files, right?

Comment: Correct. `cp -R` will, but that'll recursively copy, so you may or may not want to use that. You could do `cp Folder1/.* Folder2/` to copy only the hidden files.

Comment: Note that this will fail if you are using "sudo" or an equivalent and the directory contains a lot of files. I get `sudo: unable to execute /bin/cp: Argument list too long`

Comment: note that SCP has a slightly different syntax, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26346339/1984636

Comment: Don't do this. Do "cp -rT src dest" on Linux, or "cp -R src/ dest" on BSD.

Comment: @xpusostomos why?

Comment: @tonitone because using shell glob, aka "*" does not match hidden files, i.e. files starting with dot. Also, a very large directory could exceed the glob memory space, although that's rare.

Answer (score 50):

Quite simple, with a `*` wildcard.

```
cp -r Folder1/* Folder2/
```

But according to your example recursion is not needed so the following will suffice:

```
cp Folder1/* Folder2/
```

**EDIT:**

Or skip the `mkdir Folder2` part and just run:

```
cp -r Folder1 Folder2
```

Comment: If `ls | sort -k1.5 | head -8 > folder1` then how to do that ?

Comment: You just lost all your hidden files. Don't do this. Do "cp -rT src dest" on Linux, or "cp -R src/ dest" on BSD.

Answer (score 23):

To make an exact copy, permissions, ownership, and all use "-a" with "cp".  "-r" will copy the contents of the files but not necessarily keep other things the same.

> cp -av Source/* Dest/

(make sure Dest/ exists first)

If you want to repeatedly update from one to the other or make sure you also copy all dotfiles, `rsync` is a great help:

> rsync -av --delete Source/ Dest/

This is also "recoverable" in that you can restart it if you abort it while copying.  I like "-v" because it lets you watch what is going on but you can omit it.

Comment: what is the `-v` for?

Comment: verbose, just to watch what is going on.

Comment: If you have a lot of files the `-v` option can take some time. If you don't need the output use `-a` only.

Comment: You'd have to be running over pretty slow network connection for the copy to be slowed by text output.  And even then, it would likely just be the return of the command prompt, not the copy itself.

Comment: You lost your hidden files. Do "cp -rT src dest" on Linux, or "cp -R src/ dest" on BSD.